# action_type [NUM BER_TYPE_COERCE]: Value "ROLE_UPDATE" is not int

Tags: discord.js

I was updating my dicord bot  from 13 to 14 its is old code so i dont know from where this error is originating
ERROR

```
action_type [NUM


BER_TYPE_COERCE]: Value "ROLE_UPDATE" is not int.
```

I try finding onlin but nothing was there

Comment: What code is causing this error? Please provide more context.

Comment: It is ``` Guilde.fetchAuditLogs({type:'ROLE_UPDATE'})```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is originating from fetchAuditLogs of Guild. In v14 you have to provide a num insted of the old string you can find those no. At https://discord-api-types.dev/api/discord-api-types-v10/enum/AuditLogEvent